# The concept of software reuse

Tags: reusability, concept

I don't quite get the concept of software reuse ... Wikipedia provided "code reuse" & "re-usability" nothing specific about SOFTWARE reuse ... Please, if you could explain the concept clearly, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is self-explanatory. There is some *software* that you want to *reuse*. It is quite simple to understand.

I will use `Java` to explain reusability so please bear with me.

```
class Parent{
    int[] numbers;
    public void supplyNumbers(int[] someNumbers){
        this.numbers = someNumbers;
    }

    public void performSorting(){
        for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
            //perform sorting here
        }
    }
}
```

So there is a class `Parent` that has an array of numbers and two methods to supply the numbers and perform some sorting operation on it.
Now, I want to create another class that needs similar such functions. Instead of re-writing the code, all I would do is I would `inherit` the code as follows:

```
class Child extends Parent{

}
```

So where is the code ? Well, I do not need to write anything as it will be automatically provided to me as I have inherited it from the `Parent` class.
I am **reusing** what I wrote previously. This is code reusability.

Also, when you make `import`s in Java, you are reusing the code the devs wrote. :)

Comment: Thanks, that was more than enough ... so software re-usability is the same as code re-usability?

Comment: @SaraKholusi Basically, yes. Software is made of code so code reuse = software reuse and vice versa :)